# Swift - Best way to write an if else

Tags: swift, if-statement

I want to assign a boolean value to a variable based on a certain expression. Here's my code

Method 1 :

```
    if jobListView.tableView.jobIds.count > 0 {
        container.isHidden = false
    } else {
        container.isHidden = true
    }
```

Method 2 :

```
    container.isHidden = jobListView.tableView.jobIds.count <= 0
```

I understand that the second one is more readable but will it make any difference in execution speed.

Comment: `will it make any difference in execution speed` don't worry about it! (until it's a problem). You've already wasted more time thinking about this than you will **ever** save in execution time making micro-optimisations like this. If, when you profile, you discover part of your code is performing badly, optimise that.

Comment: @JamesWebster, I think, its worth wasting time on such things as long as I am learning and writing good quality code.

Comment: Put simply, it's not. Profile your code to find out which bits are worth learning about optimising.

Comment: @JamesWebster, Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Imagine you're building a beach. And for the first 2 months, you perfect a grain of sand, so that it's perfectly round, exactly the right coarseness and colour. It's beautiful and it's perfect. You do the same for a couple of  other types of sand. In the meantime, you've neglected the promenade, and the bars, and the ice cream stand and the trash cans, and the loungers, all the bits that you should have been interested in learning about. However, so far your project has taken you 6 months, the beach season is almost over and you've got three pretty bits of sand that nobody cares about.

Comment: If you'd built the beach so that it looked like a beach, then asked the people which bits they wanted improving, you would have discovered that there wasn't enough parking and you could have focused on optimising that instead.

Comment: @JamesWebster, Hey! Thanks for your explanation and for your precious time you have put

Comment: Apart from the issue **never** check for an empty array with `foo.count > 0`, write always `!foo.isEmpty`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I understand that the second one is more readable

That is a good argument. Start with the version that *you* (or your team) are more comfortable with.

> will it make any difference in execution speed?

As mentioned above – profile your app and find the performance 
bottlenecks. Then you can decide if this particular part needs
to be improved.

*In this particular case* it won't make a difference at all,
the compiler is smart enough to optimize both variants.
Here is a simplified self-contained example: Both

```
var hidden = false

func foo(n: Int) {
    if n > 0 {
        hidden = false
    } else {
        hidden = true
    }
}
```

and

```
var hidden = false

func foo(n: Int) {
    hidden = n <= 0
}
```

generate the *identical* assembly code

```
    .private_extern __T04main3fooySi1n_tF
    .globl  __T04main3fooySi1n_tF
    .p2align    4, 0x90
__T04main3fooySi1n_tF:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    testq   %rdi, %rdi
    setle   __T04main6hiddenSbvp(%rip)
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```

as you can verify with

```
swiftc -O -emit-assembly main.swift
```

Comment: Thanks for _actually_ answering the question and not just telling the OP that his intent is all wrong. While I agree that readability is the main concern of 99% of the code we write, it helps to know such details in order to make an informed decision in edge cases.